# Change value for multiple cells in Excel

Tags: excel

If I have an Excel sheet with lets say 2 columns **Name | Age**, and in the **Name** column I have some 2000 entries and some of them repeat more than once in a random order, how can I populate the **Age** column inserting the value only once for each unique record from the **Name** column?

Excel noobie, so sorry if the question seems stupid.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved with pivot tables and VLOOKUP!

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to use the advanced filter to copy unique values.
Alternatively you could use a countif() to identify the duplicates.
Sorting by name could also be of help.